# How to get the maximum value from a dict and determine the key where the maximum is from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
sets={'Billy': [85, 76, 92], 'Sara': [55, 90, 68], 'Ben': [100, 80, 40]}
```

I'm trying to use sets.values() but I later figured out that I have to think another way since it will be the hard way to indicate who got the highest value.

```
for i in range(len(sets.values())):
    a= list(sets.values())[i][0]
    print(a)
```

The highest value has to be picked from the first value[0] from each list that Billy, Sara, Ben has. For example, the highest value of the second score is 90 which comes from 76, 90, 80 #sets[i][1].
 The output I want is:

```
[Ben, Sara, Billy]
```

Can you give me some tips, please?

Comment: shouldnt the output be `[Ben, Billy, Sara]` in descending order of marks?

Comment: Please read the [Python sorting how-to](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Comment: Are you just sorting on the first value or are you looking the max of each index in the values? The latter result is `['Ben', 'Sara', 'Billy']` - `(100, 90, 92)`.

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake. I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you a looking for the name of the max of each index...
You can do this quite simply with a list comprehension with `max`:

```
>>> [max(sets, key=lambda x: sets[x][i]) for i in range(3)]
['Ben', 'Sara', 'Billy']
```

Comment: I wonder how can I add 'Same' if at least two of them have same score. sets={'Billy': [85, 90, 92], 'Sara': [55, 90, 68], 'Ben': [100, 80, 40]} I want to make the output like this-> ['Ben', 'Same', 'Billy'] since max() will only print Sara even though Billy and Sara have same score in second of list. Can you give me some adivices for it?

Comment: Not simply, but you could write your own `max` function. This is really separate question that you could ask SO.